# Pop-up on form validation failed

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the below code to validate a certaim field.

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["obs"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("All the fields are mandatory..");
    return false;
}
```

I try to replace the alrt action with a modal with two buttons : **Return to field** and **Leave it empty**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try zebra dialog. It is very useful plugin.
http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["obs"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
$.Zebra_Dialog('All the fields are mandatory..', {
'type':     'question',
'title':    'Custom buttons',
'buttons':  ['Return To field', 'Leave Empty'],    
});

return false;
}
```